ExTester Automated Test Visual Studio Code Change version on the Extension Plugin
When I open the plugin extension page,
When I click Uninstall more actions button,
Then install another version and uninstall options listed,
And other versions listed to change version of the plugin.
And it can't locate the Install Another Version.. submenu item:

Change Version extension:
TimeoutError: Waiting for element to be located By(xpath, //li[contains(text(), "Install Another Version...")])
Wait timed out after 15192ms

import { expect } from 'chai';
import { ExtensionsViewSection, SideBarView, ActivityBar, ExtensionsViewItem, InputBox } from 'vscode-extension-tester';
import { By, until, WebDriver } from 'selenium-webdriver';

describe('Change Version of the Plugin Extension', () => {
    let section: ExtensionsViewSection;
    let items: ExtensionsViewItem[];
    let driver: WebDriver;

    before(async function () {
        this.timeout(120000); // Increase timeout to allow more time for loading and actions

        // Open the Extensions view
        const viewControl = await new ActivityBar().getViewControl('Extensions');
        if (!viewControl) throw new Error('Extensions view not found');
        await viewControl.openView();

        // Get the Installed section in the Extensions view
        section = await new SideBarView().getContent().getSection('Installed') as ExtensionsViewSection;
        driver = section.getDriver(); // Initialize WebDriver for more granular control
    });

    it('should change the version of theP lugin extension', async () => {
        // Clear any previous searches and find installed extensions
        await section.clearSearch();
        items = await section.getVisibleItems() as ExtensionsViewItem[];

        // Find the Plugin extension in the installed section
        const plugin = items.find(async (item) => (await item.getTitle()) === 'PLugin');
        expect(plugin).to.exist;

        if (plugin) {
            const isInstalled = await plugin.isInstalled();
            expect(isInstalled).to.be.true;

            // Right-click on the plugin to open the context menu
            await plugin.openContextMenu();
            console.log('Opened context menu for Plugin extension.');

            // Select the "Install Another Version..." option from the context menu
            const installAnotherVersionItem = await driver.wait(
                until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//li[contains(text(), "Install Another Version...")]')),
                15000
            );
            await installAnotherVersionItem.click();
            console.log('Clicked "Install Another Version..." Plugin extension.');
        }
    });
});


